Docker demon not getting started in AKS cluster
I was succesful to run Docker inside docker container hosted on top of AKS v1.27 with base image of ubuntu18, but not working same way on Ubuntu22.04.
Docker is not getting started on this created Keda sclaedjob pods, but  "service docker start" starting the docker service by a manuall command.
Also when we run docker.sh first time in the container getting below error, but when rerun again second time same script,starting the docker service.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Base image as below
FROM ubuntu:22.04
#install docker daemon inside docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |  gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y

WORKDIR /azp
COPY ./vstsagent/ .
COPY ./start.sh .
COPY ./docker.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh docker.sh
CMD ["./docker.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]


The ado Image created from above base image as below..

FROM myregistry/agetImage
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y
COPY ./daemon.json /etc/docker/
COPY ./config.json /root/.docker/
WORKDIR /azp/
RUN chmod 777 start.sh
RUN chmod 777 docker.sh
RUN usermod -aG docker root
ENV AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="true"
CMD ["./docker.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh"]


docker.sh as below

#!/bin/bash
echo "DOCKER STARTS HERE"
service docker start
docker version
docker ps


daemon.json as below
{
    "storage-driver": "vfs"
}


scaledjob as below

apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    template:
      spec:
        affinity:
          nodeAffinity:
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - preference:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: kubernetes.azure.com/mode
                  operator: Exists
                  values:
                  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                - key: topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone
                  operator: Exists
                  values:
                  - westeurope-2
              weight: 2
        containers:
        - name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
          image: myregistry/vstsnew/vsts_customxxxx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1500m
              memory: 10Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 6Gi
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            privileged: true
          env:
          - name: AZP_URL
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_TOKEN
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_POOL
            value: xxxxxxxxxxxx
          - name: AZP_AGENT_NAME
            value: DockerAgentLinux
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /mnt
            name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        nodeSelector:
          agentpool: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        volumes:
        - name: xxxxxxxx
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  pollingInterval: 30
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  maxReplicaCount: 6
  minReplicaCount: 1
  scalingStrategy:
    strategy: "default"
  triggers:
  - type: azure-pipelines
    metadata:
      poolID: "xxxx"
      organizationURLFromEnv: "AZP_URL"
      personalAccessTokenFromEnv: "AZP_TOKEN"


You can't just run a Docker daemon in a container; it requires some special setup.  You could in theory try to use the prebuilt docker:dind image, but it's not usually recommended.  What are you actually trying to do with this setup?  If you need to dynamically launch containers, can you use the Kubernetes API here (or restructure your application so that it's not necessary)?

Add a health check or a sleep command to check the Docker service is fully started before proceeding.

If your goal is to build Docker images dynamically, use tools like Kaniko or BuildKit to build images directly in a Kubernetes pod without requiring Docker-in-Docker.
